# How to change the value of a column after a certain time has passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am currently working on a car booking functionality

Users are currently able to book a car by choosing the car, start_time and end_time

This is what the schema for bookings looks like:

```
 create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "car_id"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["car_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_car_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
  end
```

This is what the schema for the cars looks like:

```
create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "make"
    t.string "model"
    t.string "number_plate"
    t.string "color"
    t.string "seat_count"
    t.string "current_address"
    t.string "latitude"
    t.string "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "status", default: "Available"
  end
```

Once a booking is made the status of the car goes from "Available"to "Unavailable"and this is currently done in my bookings controller create method:

```
def create
    params[:booking][:user_id]= current_user.id
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        @booking.car.update(status: "Unavailable")  
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was 
successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: 
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is what my booking model looks like at the moment:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  validate :bookings_must_not_overlap

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car



private

def bookings_must_not_overlap
  return if self
              .class
              .where.not(id: id)
              .where(car_id: car_id)
              .where('start_time < ? AND end_time > ?', end_time, 
start_time)
              .none?

  errors.add(:base, 'The car has already been booked for that time frame')
end
```

end

The problem I am having at the moment is changing the status back to "Available" after the end_time for the booking has passed.

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jobs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) for that.

```
class ResetCarAvailabilityJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(car)
    car.update(status: "Available")
  end
end
```

And run this job with a delay after car is booked:

```
ResetCarAvailabilityJob.set(wait_until: @booking.end_time).perform_later(@booking.car)
```

Comment: Where exactly would i place that second piece of code? Sorry I have never used jobs before

Comment: In your controller, after `@booking.car.update(status: "Unavailable")`